# Use Laptop instead of Meet Hardware for Conference room

Tags: google-meet

Is it possible to use a regular Laptop instead of the dedicated Google Meet Hardware to equip a room that has been setup in G-Suite with Video Conferencing? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Well I literally googled for "Use Laptop instead of Google Meet Hardware for Conference room" but anything that comes up is about how to setup Google Meet Hardware and any official documentation on how to connect a G-Suite managed room with Meet gives only instructions on how to use Google Meet Hardware